Configuration of PLZ for K6 test in Grafana fails
I have configured a K6 performance test in combination with Grafana. I also configured a private load zone while following this documentation: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/testing/k6/author-run/private-load-zone-v2/#set-up-a-private-load-zone
This in combination with a kind container in Docker and the kubernetes cluster is working fine.
NAME                                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
k6-operator-controller-manager-5667d6469f-szzsl   2/2     Running   2 (72m ago)   20h

When I try to run a K6 test in the cloud I get this error:
ERRO[0004] (400/E4000) Invalid load zones: 'plz-abi'. Must be one of: 'amazon:us:ashburn', 'amazon:bh:bahrain', 'amazon:sa:cape town', 'amazon:us:columbus', 'amazon:ie:dublin', 'amazon:de:frankfurt', 'amazon:cn:hong kong', 'amazon:gb:london', 'amazon:it:milan', 'amazon:ca:montreal', 'amazon:in:mumbai', 'amazon:jp:osaka', 'amazon:us:palo alto', 'amazon:fr:paris', 'amazon:us:portland', 'amazon:br:sao paulo', 'amazon:kr:seoul', 'amazon:sg:singapore', 'amazon:se:stockholm', 'amazon:au:sydney', 'amazon:jp:tokyo'.

I have checked the namespace in my kubernetes cluster and it returns me:
kubectl -n plz-abi get privateloadzones.k6.io

plz-abi   20h

This cloud configuration is used in my K6 script
cloud: {
    projectID: 3682956,
    distribution: {
        private: { loadZone: "plz-abi", percent: 100 },
    },
},

Everything seems to be configured correctly but the PLZ is not found when using with Grafana
This is my yaml configuration used by Grafana
apiVersion: k6.io/v1alpha1
kind: PrivateLoadZone
metadata:  
  name: plz-abi  
  namespace: plz-abi
spec:  
  token: grafana-k6-token  
  resources:    
    limits:      
      cpu: 256m      
      memory: 1024Mi

What am I doing wrong?

Have you reached K6/Grafana Cloud support ? Feels like you did everything by the book.
